# Медленная отрисовка TreeView C#,

Tags: c#, windows, treeview

Использую стандартный treeView. Узлы добавил через свойства компонента Nodes -> Edit Nodes. Структура дерева следующая
- Главное меню
  - Начисления
    - Заработная плата
    - Отпускные
    - Больничные
    - Договора ГПХ
  - Справочники
    - Подразделения
    - Надбавки
    - Администрация
    - Спецстаж
При запуске узлы свернуты. При раскрытии узла "Начисления" - заметные тормоза. 
пробовал использовать установку свойства DoubleBuffered дерева в true. Не помогло. Как можно решить проблему скорости?

Comment: Не надо слов. Покажите код, покажите воспроизводимый пример, покажите тормоза.

Comment: Сделал видео пример. Ссылка ниже
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OrIzaAnX_rx8QDU4mypnvGjdWT8ezONK

Comment: @ДмитрийСабельников А что нам ваш видео пример? Вот вы увидите на улице машину, запорожец, вы же не знаете что у нее под капотом, может она реактивная, а может взорвется при старте.. Так и тут, мы знаем что у вас лагает, видим элемент и? Что под капотом?

Comment: Чтобы убедится, что код не влияет на скорость, я предварительно все закомментировал. Так что "под капотом", всего лишь:
        public fmMainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 }
Узлы добавлял стандартными средствами, не через код.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZHvCfe74IjgOcrscZveofBXL9oLRs7ql

Comment: Ну если у вас даже просто пустой контрол тупит, то не пора ли задуматься об чистке/апгрейде вашего пк?